# Jquery ajax Json decode in rails 3 causing error 795 unexpected token at

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, json

Jquery function

```
function user_registration() {
    jsonObj ={
            'first_name' : $('#user_first_name').val(),
            'last_name' : $('#user_last_name').val(),
            'email' : $("#user_email").val(),
            'login' : $('#user_email').val(),
            'password' : $('#password').val(),
            'password_confirmation': $('#password').val()
        }
    $.ajax({
        type : 'post',
        url : "/api/sign-up.json?chain_id=1",
        data :JSON.stringify(jsonObj),
        contentType: "application/json;",
        success : function(data) {
        },
        failure : function(data) {
            alert("failure")
        }
    });
}
```

In Rails contoller

```
params[:user] = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(request.body) 

getting error 
795: unexpected token at ''
```

json creation in jquery is not correct Or add any additional parameter required in ajax request. I can't change rails controller since it is an api function which is accessing from device also..
Kindly help me...

Generated json

```
Parameters: {"first_name"=>"test", "last_name"=>"data", "email"=>"testdata@gmail.com", "login"=>"testdata@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "chain_id"=>"1", "api_user"=>{"first_name"=>"test", "last_name"=>"data", "email"=>"testdata@gmail.com", "login"=>"testdata@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}}
```

Comment: I don't know ROR but the problem seems to be on your back-end controller. Why can't you post it's code? Or even the generated json that you're trying to decode.

Comment: can you view the request in the browser (chrome dev tools or similar)?

Comment: Add generated json...